# How to query this in Android Room?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I try Room in my app,News.class contains related, such as science, economics...

```
@Entity
public class News {
   public List<String> related = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want db can find News By related and support search by list, like mongodb(this is SpringBoot,not Android):

```
@Query(value = "{'related':{$in:?0}}")
List<News> findBySymbols(List<String> related, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you interacted with `DAO Class`?

Here are sample queries

```
// get news where id is news id 
@Query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = :newsID")
News getNews(int newsID);

// order by time of creation
@Query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY posted")
LiveData<List<news>> getTimedNews();

// get all the news
@Query("SELECT * FROM news")
LiveData<List<News>> getAllNews();
```